# How to count the average number of places between a letter in a string?

Tags: python, string, average

I have strings like so:

```
F-F-F+F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F-F-F
```

And I would like to count the average number of places between instances of 'F', '+' and '-'.
So for this example it would be:

```
Average chars between Fs:   1
Average chars between +s:   2.25
Average chars between -s:   3
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a variant.

first i collect the index `i` of the occurrences of all `char`acters; then i calculate the `mean` of the differences:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import islice
from statistics import mean

strg = "F-F-F+F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F-F-F"

dct = defaultdict(list)

for i, char in enumerate(strg):
    dct[char].append(i)

for char, occurrences in dct.items():
    avg = mean(b - a for a, b in zip(occurrences, islice(occurrences, 1, None))) - 1
    print(f"Average chars between {char}s:  {avg}")
```

this prints:

```
Average chars between Fs:  1
Average chars between -s:  3
Average chars between +s:  2.25
```

after the first for loop there will be entries like this in `dct`:

```
'-': [1, 3, 11, 13, 15, 23, 29, 33, 35, 37]
```

and - as mentioned - the second for loop calculates the mean of the differences.

Comment: And am I understanding the `islice` correct in saying it makes pairs of the index numbers?

Comment: [`islice` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice#itertools.islice). the way it is used here is basically the same as `occurrences[1:]`: it just does not create a new list.

Comment: Great! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would do that using regular expressions (`re` module) following way:

```
import re
txt = "F-F-F+F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F-F-F"
chars = set(list(txt))
between = dict()
for i in chars:
    between[i] = re.findall('(?<='+re.escape(i)+').*?(?='+re.escape(i)+')',txt)
for i in chars:
    if len(between[i])==0:
        between[i] = 0.0
    else:
        between[i] = sum([len(i) for i in between[i]])/len(between[i])
print(between)
```

Output:

```
{'F': 1.0, '+': 2.25, '-': 3.0}
```

Explanation: I am looking for substrings between occurences given character (using zero length assertions) from left to right workng in non-greedy manner (hence `"F-F-F"` give `["-","-"]` rather than `["-F-"]`) then simply calculate averages of their lengths. Note that I used `re.escape` to deal with characters of special meaning (like `+`).

Comment: Can someone knowledgeable ;) corroborate?

Answer (score 0):

Another way without using any libraries:

```py
string = 'F-F-F+F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F-F-F'
string = list(string)
chars = set(string)
for char in chars:
    ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(string) if x == char]
    diff = [ind[i+1]-ind[i] - 1 for i in range(len(ind)-1)]
    print(f'Average chars between {char}s:  {sum(diff) / len(diff)}')
```

Output:

```
Average chars between +s:  2.25
Average chars between Fs:  1.0
Average chars between -s:  3.0
```